# AWS Lambda Extract Comprehend Record Data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, parsing, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function which takes in an SQS queue as an event, parses the data and uses it to start an AWS Transcribe job. The results of this Transcribe job are then sent to AWS Comprehend for sentiment analysis. I'm having trouble extracting the relevant data from the record returned by Comprehend even though I'm doing so in the same way as I parsed data from the queue/transcribe.

My Lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    ## Queue parsing omitted
    for record in event['Records']:
         while True:
            result = transcribe.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName = job_name)
            if result['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobStatus'] in ['COMPLETED', 'FAILED']:
                break
            time.sleep(15)
        if result['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobStatus'] == "COMPLETED":
            data = result['TranscriptionJob']['Transcript']['TranscriptFileUri']
            http = urllib3.PoolManager()
            data = http.request('GET', result['TranscriptionJob']['Transcript']['TranscriptFileUri'])
            data = json.loads(data.data.decode('utf-8'))
        transcriptionText = data['results']['transcripts'][0]['transcript']
        print(transcriptionText)
        

        # Start comprehend service
        print('Starting comprehend job.')
        comprehend = boto3.client('comprehend')
        detectedSentimentRecord = comprehend.detect_sentiment(
            Text = transcriptionText,
            LanguageCode = 'en'
        )
        
        print(detectedSentimentRecord)

        # detectedSentimentRecord = json.loads(detectedSentimentRecord)
        # detectedSentiment = detectedSentimentRecord['Sentiment']
        posScore = detectedSentimentRecord['Sentiment']['SentimentScore']['Positive']
        negScore = detectedSentimentRecord['Sentiment']['SentimentScore']['Negative']
        neutScore = detectedSentimentRecord['Sentiment']['SentimentScore']['Neutral']
        mixScore = detectedSentimentRecord['Sentiment']['SentimentScore']['Mixed']
```

The output of print(detectedSentimentRecord):

```
{'Sentiment': 'NEGATIVE', 'SentimentScore': {'Positive': 0.00016704350127838552, 'Negative': 0.9995306730270386, 'Neutral': 0.00016289811173919588, 'Mixed': 0.00013944115198682994}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '59f51f02-2b8a-47f7-9a7b-397daa3a6648', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '59f51f02-2b8a-47f7-9a7b-397daa3a6648', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '168', 'date': 'Mon, 29 Mar 2021 19:23:58 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

The error I receive is 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'.

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: `posScore = detectedSentimentRecord['Sentiment']['SentimentScore']['Positive']`

Comment: Try `posScore = detectedSentimentRecord['SentimentScore']['Positive']`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks for your help.